# Sed keep original indentation and camel-casing a variable

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have a simple sed script and I am replacing a bunch of lines in my application dynamically with a variable, the variable is a list of strings.My function works but does not keep the original indentation.the function deletes the line if it contains the certain string and replaces the line with a completely new line, I could not do a replace due to certain syntax restrictions.

1. How do I keep my original indentation when the line is replaced
2. Can I capitalize my variable and remove the underscore on the fly, i.e. the title is a capitalize and underscore removed version of the variableName, the list of items in the variable array is really long so I am trying to do this in one shot.
   Ex: I want report_type -> Report Type done mid process

Is there a better way to solve this with sed? Thanks for any inputs much appreciated.
sed function is as follows

```
variableName=$1
sed -i "/name\=\"${variableName}\.name\" value\=model\.${variableName}\.name options\=\@lists\./c\\{\{\> \_dropdown title\=\"${variableName}\" required\=true name\=\"${variableName}\"\}\}" test
```

SAMPLE INPUT

```
      {{> _select title="Report Type" required=true name="report_type.name" value=model.report_type.name options=@lists.report_type}}
```

SAMPLE EXPECTED OUPUT

```
      {{> _dropdown title="Report Type" required=true name="report_type" value=model.report_type.name}}
```

sample input variable
report_type

Comment: We don't need the extra sample data. Can't you describe this in 3-4 words of sample input and expected output? Good luck.

Comment: hahah sorry you are very right, a simpler input and ouput would have made life easier for all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed -E "s/^(\s+).*name\=\"(report_type)\.name\" value\=model\.report_type\.name options\=\@lists\..*$/\1\{\{\> \_dropdown title\=\"\2\" required\=true name\=\"\2\"\}\}/;T;s/\"(\w+)_(\w+)\"/\"\u\1 \u\2\"/g" input.txt > output.txt
```

I used "report_type" instead of `${variableName}` for testing as an sed one-liner.
Please change back to `${variableName}`.

Then go back to using `-i` (in addition to `-E`, which is for extended regex).
I am not sure whether I can do it without extended regex, let me know if that is necessary.

- use `s///` to replace fine tuned line
- first capture group for the white space making the indentation
- second capture group for the variable name
- stop if that did not replace anything, `T;`
- another `s///`
- look for something consisting of only letters between `""`,
  with a "_" between two parts,
  seems safe enough because this step is only done on the already replaced line
- replace by two parts, without "_"
- `\u` for making camel case

Note:
Doing this on your sample input creates two very similar lines.
I assume that is intentional. Otherwise please provide desired output.

Using GNU sed version 4.2.1.

Interesting line of output:

```
      {{> _dropdown title="Report Type" required=true name="Report Type"}}
```

Comment: hey this is exactly the output I wanted for the title, the name I wanted to keep as report_type, BUT I should be able to work with this thank you so much!!!! also this looks complicated ahhhhh

Comment: Happy that it is good enough. I am not so advanced to be "elegant" or "fast" or "efficient", still crawling around at "get it done somehow". You might want an awk solution maybe. If you update the question with more sample input lines (maybe **single** relevant input lines ;-) ) and desired output I will fine tune if you like. If you simplify  then I can also test more directly.

Comment: Hey I updated the question to a more concise loo if you wanted to take another crack at it and fine tune, if not no worries your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure whether I got correctly what should be derived from variable content and what should be literal. Try `sed -E "s/^(\s*)\{\{> _select (title=)(\")[[:alpha:] ]+(\" required=true name=.)([[:alpha:]]+)_([[:alpha:]]+)(\.name).*$/\1\{\{\> _dropdown \2\3\u\5 \u\6\4 \5_\6\3 value=model.\5_\6\7}}/;" input.txt > output.txt`. This does not use variable content at all. We can use a condition, so that replacing only occurs when variable content is inside the line.